# Finding the explicit formula of linear homogeneous recurrence relations.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm not sure if this equation is a linear homogeneous recurrence relation because I didn't learn math in english.
what is the explicit formula for $f$?

$$f(x) = f(x-2)-{n^{x-1}\over NW-1} f(x-1)+n^{x-1}$$

$n$ and $NW$ are constants. $n = 3$ and  $NW = 7000000000 = $7 billion
I'm having a hard time because of the $n^{x-1}$
please help me.

Comment: I'm having hard time reading it. Please, use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should read [this](meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before posting questions

Comment: Please review and edit your post.  Is $m$ supposed to be the same as $n$?  What is NW-?  is the $*nf(d-1)$ supposed to be in the denominator or numerator?

Comment: sorry, I didn't know how to use it, and i got many miss spellings.

Comment: Is the second term on the right hand side really $-[f(x-1)]^2/(NW-1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linear second order recurrence with variable coefficients. Just as in the case of differential equations, there are few such recurrences with closed form solutions.

As a first approximation (for smallish $x$) you can disregard the term in $f(x - 1)$, and get a first order linear recurrence (of step two) in $f(x)$:

$$
f(x) - f(x - 2) = n^{x - 1}
$$

This has solution:

$$
f(2 x) = f(0) + \sum_{0 \le k \le x} n^{k - 1}
       = f(0) +  \frac{n^{x + 1} - 1}{n (n - 1)}
$$

This might be enough for your purposes, or use this as a starting point to construct a closer approximation.